# RemoveChild when node is empty

Tags: c#, xml, removechild

I want to remove some child elements from an XML structure using `RemoveChild()` if a node is empty. My XML:

```
<Customers>
<customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Status></Status>
</Customer>
<customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age></Age>
    <Status></Status>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

Should become:

```
<Customers>
<customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
</Customer>
<customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

My code so far:

```
XmlElement element3 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Age");
        element3.InnerText = str3;
        element1.AppendChild((XmlNode)element3);    
XmlElement element4 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Status");
        element4.InnerText = str4;
        element1.AppendChild((XmlNode)element4);
```

How can I remove the empty node resp. nodes if there is more than one empty node?

Comment: `element5` and `str56` are really bad names for variables. I highly recommend that you change them to something meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to only create the element if you need to:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
{
    XmlElement statusElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Status");
    statusElement.InnerText = status;
    customerElement.AppendChild((XmlNode)statusElement);
}
```

Or if you need to remove it after it's already created (e.g. because you get XML from an external source with an empty `Status`), use the same sort of condition to remove it:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
{
    customerElement.RemoveChild(statusElement);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim S. after i paste the code into my xml. the status still appear when i output the xml. and how if there are more then 1 empty node have to be remove ? do i need to paste every code on it ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to remove a child element that simply does not exist. You must understand that in this context, the RemoveChild() method expects a reference to an existing node within the parent's children.

If i were to use your code sample above and create a standalone representation of this, it would look like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement("Customer");
        XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        element2.InnerText = "John";
        element1.AppendChild(element2);
        XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement("Age");
        element3.InnerText = "25";
        element1.AppendChild(element3);
        XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement("Status");
        element4.InnerText="";
        element1.AppendChild(element4);
        doc.AppendChild(element1);
        element1.RemoveChild(element1.SelectSingleNode("Status"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq-to-XML:

If you want nodes like:

```
<a>
   <b>
       <c></c>
   </b>
</a>
```

to become:

```
<a />
```

Use:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
root.Descendants().Reverse().ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (x.IsEmpty)
            x.Remove();
    });
```

But if you want it to be:

```
<a>
    <b />
</a>
```

Remove the `.Reverse()`